# libdnet is installed but can't be found by snort

Tags: fedora, package-management, libraries, snort

I'm running Fedora 22 and just installed snort:

```
sudo dnf install snort
```

When trying to run it I get:

```
$ snort 
snort: error while loading shared libraries: libdnet.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Yet I have the latest version of `libdnet` and `libdnet-devel` packages installed:

```
$ locate libdnet
/usr/lib64/libdnet.so
/usr/lib64/libdnet.so.1
/usr/lib64/libdnet.so.1.0.1
/usr/local/lib/libdnet.so.1.0.1
/usr/share/doc/libdnet
/usr/share/doc/libdnet/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/libdnet/README
/usr/share/doc/libdnet/THANKS
/usr/share/doc/libdnet/TODO
```

I'm not sure what to do from here, does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit**

```
$ rpm -q --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n" snort
snort-2.9.7.3-1.x86_64
```

Comment: What does `rpm -q --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n" snort` say?

Comment: Hi @John, I've updated my question with the output of your command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also upgraded recently to Fedora 22 and experienced the same issue. I resolved it by creating a symlink called libd.1 which points to (in my case) libdnet.so.1.0.1:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libdnet.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib64/libdnet.1
```

After that Snort worked

Comment: also works perfectly on snort-2.9.16-1.x86_64 on CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)